# Is there a way to use Nadam optimizer on scikit-learn MLPClassifier?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use diferent optimizers for an [scikit-learn's MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). As far as their docs show, there is only a few `solvers`(MLPClassifier's optimizer parameter) available, which are:

> - ‘lbfgs’ is an optimizer in the family of quasi-Newton methods.
> - ‘sgd’ refers to stochastic gradient descent.
> - ‘adam’ refers to a stochastic gradient-based optimizer proposed by Kingma, Diederik, and Jimmy Ba

What I'm trying to use is another one called [Nadam](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2015/054_report.pdf). I've tried to mix some parameters to achieve it with `solver='adam'` and `nesterovs_momentum=True`, but sklearn's docs says that the last parameter is only used for `sgd`:

> Whether to use Nesterov’s momentum. Only used when solver=’sgd’ and momentum > 0.

I've tried the above because I've thought that meant what [keras's nadam](https://keras.io/optimizers/#nadam) stated:

> Much like Adam is essentially RMSprop with momentum, Nadam is RMSprop with Nesterov momentum.

Because of all this, I don't think I'm doing the right thing. My code below shows what I've done so far.

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', nesterovs_momentum=True,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supply `nesterovs_momentum` to `adam` optimizer.

To see this you should have a look at [BaseMultilayerPerceptron](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/11934e1838b87936da98de31350d88158a8640bb/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L42) code on github.

Compare the params accepted by [SGDOptimizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/11934e1838b87936da98de31350d88158a8640bb/sklearn/neural_network/_stochastic_optimizers.py#L74) with those accepted by [AdamOptimizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/11934e1838b87936da98de31350d88158a8640bb/sklearn/neural_network/_stochastic_optimizers.py#L188).

You will see that `adam` simply doesn't accept `nesterovs_momentum`.